# Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.sqlite.JDBC]

Tags: spring, hibernate, sqlite

I'm trying to use Hibernate with sqlite.  I downloaded an SQLiteDialect.java file from GitHub which seems to be working fine, but I still get the "Unable to load class" error.  I think it has something to do with my application-context but I'm not sure what it could be.  Here's the full application-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="metrolink"/>

    <bean id="sessionfactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>Metrolink</value>
                <value>MetrolinkCalculator</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/metrolink.db" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org    /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mikemenne.launchcode</groupId>
  <artifactId>mqsa</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>


</project>
```

If you need anything else, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the `sqlite-jdbc.jar` add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.20</version>
</dependency>
```

To your pom file